# Declaration terminated incorrectly in C (curly bracket)

Tags: c

I am currently building a program that reads in an amount (assuming its a whole number of a factor of 5) and then reads out what how many coins of each type the register operator should give to the customer. I'm Australian so you'll notice it's in 50c, 20c, 10c and 5c.

My question is the error I am getting in line 10 or the line just after the PrintDisplay function. The compiler says:

```
Declaration terminated incorrectly
```

but all I see is a `{`?

Have I incorrectly put the following `}` or is there another error that I am too blind to see?

Here is the code: (I have also included stdio.h but it looks weird when in the draft)

```
void PrintDisplay(void);
{   
    printf("Enter an amount to calculate change: \n ");
    return;
}


int GetChange(void)
{
    int change;
    scanf("%d%*c", &change);
    return(change);
}


int CalculateChange(int change)
{
    int FiftyCentAmount = 0;
    int TwentyCentAmount = 0;
    int TenCentAmount = 0;
    int FiveCentAmount = 0;

    if(change >= 50)
    {
        FiftyCentAmount++;
        change = (change - 50);
    }

    else if(change >= 20)
    {
        TwentyCentAmount++;
        change = (change - 20);
    }

    else if(change >= 10)
    {
        TenCentAmount++;
        change = (change - 10);
    }

    else if(change >= 5)
    {
        FiveCentAmount++;
        change = (change - 5);
    }
    return(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount);
}


void PrintResult(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount)
{
    printf("The amount of each coin denomination you should give are: /n");
    printf("50c: %d%*c /n", FiftyCentAmount);
    printf("20c: %d%*c /n", TwentyCentAmount);
    printf("10c: %d%*c /n", TenCentAmount);
    printf("5c: %d%*c /n", FiveCentAmount);
    return;
}


int main(void)
{
    PrintDisplay();
    GetChange(int change);
    CalculateChange(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmountCentAmount, int FiveCentAmountCentAmount);
    PrintResult(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` here `void PrintDisplay(void);`.

Comment: Look at the semicolon on the first line.

Comment: Consider indenting your code (e.g. with GNU [indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) or [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)...). That should help find such bugs and make your code more readable. Then compile it with all warnings & debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: I think there is one more problem in this code in the function calculatechange() is returning more than one values i dont think so we can do that this way.

Comment: What do you think `return(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount);` is doing?

Comment: oh i got it we can return the arguments of the function.or correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @AmitojSingh You were correct initially.  Only a single value can be returned from a function.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons actually i visited this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-can-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function/ this changed my mind

Comment: or either i am not able to understand what this website is trying to say

Comment: @AmitojSingh It's basically explaining tricks in how you can work with the language to effectively give multiple things back to the callee, but it remains still a single value returned.  If you return a struct with many members, that struct is the single value returned.  If you return a pointer to an array with multiple members, that pointer is the single value returned.  And then the last thing it mentions is passing in pointers to your function, so now that function can dereference the pointer and change the value in that address that the caller knows about, but that does not involve return.

Comment: Hmmm, understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many errors:

```
void PrintDisplay(void);   // Do not put a semi-colon when defining a function.
{   
printf("Enter an amount to calculate change: \n ");
return;
}

int CalculateChange(int change)
{
int FiftyCentAmount = 0;
int TwentyCentAmount = 0;
int TenCentAmount = 0;
int FiveCentAmount = 0;

[ .... ]

// C cannot return multiple variables at once.  A function can have ONE and ONLY ONE return value.
return(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount); 
}

void PrintResult(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount)
{
[...]
return;  // An empty return statement is not needed.  When a void-function reaches the end, it automatically returns.
}

int main(void)
{
    // Declare your variables before using them!
    int change;
    int FiftyCentAmount;
    int TwentyCentAmount;
    int TenCentAmountCentAmount;
    int FiveCentAmountCentAmount;

    PrintDisplay();

    // Do not write the type when calling a function
    // GetChange(change);
    GetChange(int change);

    // Do not write the type when calling a function.
    // CalculateChange(FiftyCentAmount, TwentyCentAmount, TenCentAmountCentAmount, FiveCentAmountCentAmount);

    CalculateChange(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmountCentAmount, int FiveCentAmountCentAmount);
    PrintResult(int FiftyCentAmount, int TwentyCentAmount, int TenCentAmount, int FiveCentAmount);
return(0);
}
```

There are more errors, but that is enough to at least get the program to compile!

---

You asked about a function modifying its parameters as a substitute for returning multiple values.

Here is the really short answer:
(*deep understanding only comes with time*)

- Call the function with `&` in front of each variable you wish to modify.
- The function receives each parameter with `*`
- The function refers to each parameter as `*name`

**Example**

```
// Declare the function:
void GetLightning(int* day, int* month, int* year, int *hour, int *minute);

// Define the function:
void GetLightning(int* day, int* month, int* year, int *hour, int *minute)
{
*day    = 12;
*month  = 11; // November
*year   = 1955;
*hour   = 10;
*minute = 4;
}


int main(void)
{
int day;
int month;
int year;
int hour;
int minute;

// Call the function
GetLightning(&day, &month, &year, &hour, &minute);

// Show the results:
printf("Lightning will strike the clocktower at precisely %02d:%02d on %d/%d/%d!\n", hour, minute, month, day, year);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for being understanding :) This has helped me alot! You can obviously tell my parsing of functions isnt the greatest but i am working on it haha. Thankyou again. I'll be back with some more questions on this thread :)

Comment: I can't think of a way that could simplify my nest if else function to calculate how many 50c, 20c, etc. I would need. Is there a better way to use the function over and over again instead of returning multiple values?

Comment: Ignored.   Post a new question; ***do not*** use the comments for questions.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` on first line as it is a function.
As also  mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

On the first line you are defining a function and function definitions in C don't terminate with a semicolon `;`. Function declarations do (which won't have the function body).

Removing that semicolon on the first line would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Alvits already answered in comment.  Looks like you have an unintended semicolon on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

On the first line the semicolon at the end of `void PrintDisplay(void);` turns your function definition into a declaration.

The body following the function is read as being part of its own statement

```
{   
printf("Enter an amount to calculate change: \n ");
return;
}
```

This section on it's own is not valid C, resulting in the error.

Remove the `;` after `PrintDisplay` to turn it back into a function definition and the `Declaration terminated incorrectly` error should go away.